# Convert XAML path to SVG

Tags: xaml, svg, path

I have the following XAML path which I want to convert to SVG. Is there a way to do it?

```
<Path Stroke="{DynamicResource ForegroundColorBrush}" Canvas.Right="0" Width="186" Height="216" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="3" StrokeStartLineCap="Round" StrokeEndLineCap="Round" StrokeLineJoin="Round" Data="F1 M 184.69,166.333L 173.338,166.333L 173.338,80.8143L 153.122,15.4178L 153.122,5.35669C 152.785,4.01523 152.448,2.67374 140.823,2.00302C 129.199,1.33228 106.287,1.33228 94.6631,2.00302C 83.0388,2.67374 82.7018,4.01523 82.3649,5.35669L 82.3649,15.4178L 62.1486,80.8143L 62.1486,166.333L 1.49997,166.333L 1.49997,206.577L 62.1486,206.577L 62.1486,211.607C 65.1811,212.613 68.2135,213.62 85.2288,214.123C 102.244,214.626 133.242,214.626 150.258,214.123C 167.273,213.62 170.305,212.613 173.338,211.607L 173.338,206.577L 184.7,206.5" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                    <Path.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="-1"/>
                    </Path.RenderTransform>
                </Path>
```

Comment: sure, just read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/path-markup-syntax?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8 and https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathData seems pretty straightforward to map from one to the other

Comment: Yes, seems pretty simple. Thanks.

Comment: You could try this tool: https://github.com/KyleMit/XAML-to-SVG